# How do you inspect a view model object bound to a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, google-chrome-devtools

When you have data-binding between a view model and a DOM element (like with Knockout), you can pinpoint and see the DOM element in DevTools -- but how do you inspect the model object that's bound to it -- similar to how you would be able to see an object's content by inserting breakpoints at runtime?

Comment: For React there's an Chrome's extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) to do this (and more). Does Knockout have any similar?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this must have tool for knockout developers.
[KnockoutJS Context Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en)

It allows you to see the viewmodel bound to the element you picked.
[image: Sample viewing of viewmodel]

Answer (score 1):

For `Knockout` you can use the `ko.dataFor(element)` and `ko.contextFor(element)`.

From the [unobtrusive event handling](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) documentation:

```
$(".remove").click(function () {
    viewModel.items.remove(ko.dataFor(this));
});
```